# Horizontal scroll on ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm currently capturing the `PointerMoved` event on the page to use with a horizontal menu. So the user can swipe left/right and the page will animate accordingly.

This works when the user touches a static element (TextBlock etc.) but if they touch a ListView it captures the touch events.

How can I implement the ListView so when the user scrolls vertically it works as normal, but when the user scrolls horizontally it passes the events to my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible, but you will need a small trick. As a refference I put here [Rob Caplan's article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/02/16/where-did-all-my-gestures-go.aspx).

Let's start:

1. First - where are your events? - answer is simple - while you have `ScrollViewer` enabled, all events are intercepted by it and handeled. You `ListView` will get only `PointerEntered` event and just after it `PointerExited`, all further proccesing is handeled by `ScrollViewer`. That is the problem. But as I've said there is a method to do what you want.
2. For this purpose lets assume that you have defined your `ListView` only with VerticalScroll:

   ```
   <ListView Name="myList" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled">
   ```

   Of course it is possible to do for both directions, but it's a simple example.
3. Now let's have a look at constructor of a `Page`:

   ```
   PointerPoint firstPoint = null;
   ScrollViewer listScrollviewer = null;

   public MainPage()
   {
     this.InitializeComponent();
     myList.ItemsSource = yourItemSource;
     myList.PointerEntered += myList_PointerEntered;
     myList.PointerMoved += myList_PointerMoved;
   }
   ```

   Nothing weird here - I just subscribe to events, and declare two variables `firstPoint` and    `listScrollviewer`, which I'll need later.
4. We will need also to get our `ScrollViewer` of our `ListView` - the following method will do the job:

   ```
   public static ScrollViewer GetScrollViewer(DependencyObject depObj)
   {
       if (depObj is ScrollViewer) return depObj as ScrollViewer;

       for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
       {
           var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

           var result = GetScrollViewer(child);
           if (result != null) return result;
       }
       return null;
   }
   ```
5. Now - to enable our events we will need to disable the `ScrollViewer`:

   ```
   private ScrollViewer DisableScrolling(DependencyObject depObj)
   {
       ScrollViewer foundOne = GetScrollViewer(depObj);
       if (foundOne != null) foundOne.VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Disabled;
       return foundOne;
   }
   ```
6. We will disable the `ScrollViewer` upon `PointerEntered` event which is fired. In this step we will also remember the pressed `PointerPoint` - as we have disable `Scrollviewer`, we will have to scroll it manually - that is what we need this `PointerPoint` for.

   ```
   private void myList_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       firstPoint = e.GetCurrentPoint(myList);
       if (listScrollviewer == null) listScrollviewer = DisableScrolling(myList);
   }
   ```
7. Finally our `PointerMoved` event, which now wil be fired as we had disabled `ScrollViewer` - moving `ScrollViewer` + other code you need to put there:

   ```
   private void myList_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       if (listScrollviewer != null)
       {
           PointerPoint secondPoint = e.GetCurrentPoint(myList);
           double verticalDifference = secondPoint.Position.Y - firstPoint.Position.Y;
           listScrollviewer.ChangeView(null, listScrollviewer.VerticalOffset - verticalDifference, null);
       }
       // some other code you need
   }
   ```

---

Few remarks:

- this method still needs much tuning, but hopefuly will show you how to achieve your goal,
- you may need also to separate some small horizontal movements from vertical ones,
- if your `ListView` or other Control has horizontal scroll, then you will also need to disable and handle it,
- this method won't probably work so smooth like original `ScrollViewer`.

I've also put a simple working example [here at OneDrive](http://1drv.ms/1nR2k7I).