# Windows Phone 8.1 Manipulation Events do not fire

Tags: c#, xaml, event-handling, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to use the Manipulation Events on Windows Phone 8.1 on a ListView, but none of the Manipulation events fire. Pointer events fire, but they work in a very strange way, I need the Manipulation Events. Even if I try to trigger an event on a parent element nothing fires. I found a [Youtube Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rNVUVwqgb6c) that does what I need, however it doesnt work on Windows Phone 8.1. Also this [Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/73231f65-bcaa-48a6-8cb7-700b6ca42697/manipulation-events-are-not-fired-on-page-with-a-listview?forum=wpdevelop) where a person seems to be having the same problem, and someone says they added the events just fine(no code snippet though). I tried adding the events to parent elements and nothing fired, I tried taking the ScrollViewer of the ListView and adding the events to that and nothing fired, I even tried changing the ListView to a ListBox and still no events fired. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        ItemLV.DataContext = Items.DealsCollection;

        ItemLV.ManipulationStarted += ItemLV_ManipulationStarted;
    }

    private void ItemLV_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Pivot Grid.Row="1" x:Name="Pivot">
        <PivotItem Margin="0,-5,0,0">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="frontpage" Foreground="#0072bc" FontSize="30" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                <ListView x:Name="ItemLV" IsItemClickEnabled="True" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel></StackPanel>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid x:Name="ItemGrid" Margin="0,2,0,0">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="110"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Image Source="{Binding ImgUrl}" Stretch="Uniform" Canvas.ZIndex="2" Margin="5,5,5,2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition/>
                                        <RowDefinition/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" 
                                               VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                               FontSize="18" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black"/>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}" 
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                                   FontSize="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#0075DB"/>
                                        <Image Source="Assets/flame.gif" Visibility="{Binding Firedeal, Converter={StaticResource ImageBoolConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,3,0,0"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ExtraInfo}" Grid.Row="2"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                                   FontSize="16" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#569B1A"
                                                   Visibility="{Binding ExtraInfo, Converter={StaticResource LengthConverter}}">
                                        </TextBlock>
                                    <Grid Grid.Row="3">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Store}"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                                   FontSize="16" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#666"/>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Rating}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                                   FontSize="16" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black"/>
                                            <Image Source="Assets/tup.png" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="2,0,5,0" />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Comments}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                                   FontSize="16" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black"/>
                                            <Image Source="Assets/comment.png" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,4,3,0" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                                <Border BorderThickness="0,2,0,0" BorderBrush="#0072bc" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </Grid>
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Do you find a solution?

Answer (score 4):

You will not get manipulation event because the ListView has it's [ManipulationMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.manipulationmode.aspx) set to System. According to [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.manipulationstarted.aspx):

> An element must have a ManipulationMode value other than None or System to be a manipulation event source.

I would not recommend changing the mode as it will most likely stop scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.ItemLV.AddHandler(UIElement.ManipulationStartedEvent,new ManipulationStartedEventHandler(ItemLV_ManipulationStarted), true);
 }
```

Try this Link [Horizontal scroll on ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665411/horizontal-scroll-on-listview/23672239#23672239)

Comment: For `ManipulationCompleted` I Had to use this: `control.AddHandler(System.Windows.UIElement.ManipulationCompletedEvent, 
        new EventHandler<System.Windows.Input.ManipulationCompletedEventArgs>(control_ManipulationCompleted), true);`