# Get Scroll Viewer of List View Windows phone 8.1

Tags: listview, data-binding, windows-phone-8.1, scrollviewer

I need to get scroll viewer of List view to implement lazy loading in list view. For this I have referenced this
http://windowsapptutorials.com/windows-phone-8-1/listview/lazy-loading-listview/
the function i used to retrieve scrollviewer is

```
public static ScrollViewer GetScrollViewer(DependencyObject depObj)
{
if (depObj is ScrollViewer) return depObj as ScrollViewer;

for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
{
    var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

    var result = GetScrollViewer(child);
    if (result != null) return result;
}
return null;
}
```

the problem is VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount is always 0 and The function returns null. How to get scrollviewer of Listview ?

Comment: Where do you try to get this *ScrollViewer*?

Comment: @Romasz In List loaded event. I tried it in some other places too. But, it returns 0 only

Comment: At the end of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23672239/2681948) you will find a sample, can you try if it works? It's also getting scrollviewer the same way.

Comment: Is could be visibility issue? Ensure that it is visible before trying to get ScrollViewer.

Answer (score 0):

WinRT xaml toolkit provides an extension for the VisualTreeHelper, that adds a GetFirstDecendantOfType. Just use that.

See [Source on Codeplex](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/WinRTXamlToolkit.Shared/Controls/Extensions/VisualTreeHelperExtensions.cs).