# How to add touch manipulation events for a Grid in Windows 10 UWP?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am currently working on Windows 10 and I want to add swipe gesture for the user. So I did some research and came across **Manipulation Events**. I have tried the following code but it works on when I use mouse pointer not when using touch swipe gesture.

```
 pageLayoutGrid.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.TranslateX;
 pageLayoutGrid.ManipulationDelta += PageLayoutGrid_ManipulationDelta;
 pageLayoutGrid.ManipulationCompleted += LayoutManipulationCompleted;

 private void PageLayoutGrid_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void LayoutManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var velocities = e.Velocities.Linear;
        Double swipeLeftRight = velocities.X;
        Double swipeUpDown = velocities.Y;
        // A negative value means swiping to the left
        if (swipeLeftRight < 0)
        {
            navigateToNextPage();
        }
        // a positive value is a swipe to the right.
        else if (swipeLeftRight > 0)
        {
            navigateToPreviousPage();
        }
    }
```

Child element of this Grid is ScrollViewer.

Can someone please suggest what is the issue with the code?

Comment: Did you set the manipulation mode in grid?

Comment: Yes check first line

Comment: I think you need only TranslateX

Comment: Yes but it only works with mouse pointer not touch input

Comment: Yeah it's mostly because scroll viewer as said in answer. If you remove scroll viewer does it work?

Comment: I can't remove scroll viewer, as I require it

Comment: I told just to check whether it's the problem of scrollviewer

Comment: Yes, I tried removing the scrollViewer and the touch events worked. I replace the scrollViewer with Grid but how to add vertical scrolling for it then? Also, even I tried to scroll it fires manipulation event even if I have removed `TranslateY`

Comment: You need scrollviewer for scrolling. Try disabling horizontal scroll mode of scrollviewer

Comment: tried but no luck.

Comment: Try this  pageLayoutGrid.AddHandler(UIElement.ManipulationDeltaEvent, new ManipulationDeltaEventHandler(PageLayoutGrid_ManipulationDelta),true);
            pageLayoutGrid.AddHandler(UIElement.ManipulationCompletedEvent, new ManipulationCompletedEventHandler(LayoutManipulationCompleted), true);  instead of  pageLayoutGrid.ManipulationDelta += PageLayoutGrid_ManipulationDelta;
 pageLayoutGrid.ManipulationCompleted += LayoutManipulationCompleted;

Comment: It's not easy to handle scrollviewer along with pointer events - it intercepts them at low level. You will probably have to move your scrollviewer manually - you can find some help [at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23672239/2681948).

Comment: @LovetoCode Your solution is not working :-(

Comment: What is the child of Grid? A ScrollViewer or ListView?

Comment: Child of grid is ScrollViewer

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar did you try the solution?

Comment: No will try it, but can you also check other question, that I posted in comments..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a reference to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665411/horizontal-scroll-on-listview/23672239#23672239) here is the solution

I'm disabling `ScrollViewer`  `VerticalScrollMode`  in `PointerEntered` event of `ScrollViewer` so that Grid Manipulation events will be called. Enable the `VerticalScrollMode`  Once Manipulation is completed ie in `ManipulationCompleted` event

```
ScrollViewer scroolviewr;
        private void ScrollViewer_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            scroolviewr = (sender as ScrollViewer); 
            (sender as ScrollViewer).VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Disabled;
        }
private void PageLayoutGrid_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void LayoutManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        scroolviewr.VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Enabled;
        var velocities = e.Velocities.Linear;
        Double swipeLeftRight = velocities.X;
        Double swipeUpDown = velocities.Y;
        // A negative value means swiping to the left
        if (swipeLeftRight < 0)
        {
            navigateToNextPage();
        }
        // a positive value is a swipe to the right.
        else if (swipeLeftRight > 0)
        {
            navigateToPreviousPage();
        }
    }




 <Grid ManipulationMode="TranslateX" ManipulationDelta="Grid_ManipulationDelta" ManipulationCompleted="Grid_ManipulationCompleted">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" PointerEntered="ScrollViewer_PointerEntered">
    .....
    </ScrollViewer>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Sorry I havent worked on that. But i tried to give the solution. Itseems difficult to work with RichEditBox,since it has limitied permissions to edit the texts

Answer (score 1):

ScrollViewer will shallow any touch input by default. If you wish to handle the touch gesture, then the scrolling feature will be lost.

Solution can vary depend on your need. If you need completely control over handling touch gesture, ScollViewer is not for you, replace it with other Panel.

If you only need partly gesture handling, you can set the ManipulationMode to something like `TranslateX, System`. The result is you can handle gesture along X axis, and the rest is handle by ScrollViewer.

**Code Sample**

xaml file:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Sample.TestTextBox"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Sample"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ListViewStyle1" TargetType="ListView">
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Once"/>
            <Setter Property="IsSwipeEnabled" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Disabled"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Enabled"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.ZoomMode" Value="Disabled"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="ItemContainerTransitions">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TransitionCollection>
                        <AddDeleteThemeTransition/>
                        <ContentThemeTransition/>
                        <ReorderThemeTransition/>
                        <EntranceThemeTransition IsStaggeringEnabled="False"/>
                    </TransitionCollection>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListView">
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" >
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled}" IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" TabNavigation="{TemplateBinding TabNavigation}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" ZoomMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ZoomMode}">
                                <ItemsPresenter FooterTransitions="{TemplateBinding FooterTransitions}" FooterTemplate="{TemplateBinding FooterTemplate}" Footer="{TemplateBinding Footer}" HeaderTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Header="{TemplateBinding Header}" HeaderTransitions="{TemplateBinding HeaderTransitions}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" ManipulationMode="TranslateX, System"/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" ManipulationMode="TranslateX" ManipulationDelta="Grid_ManipulationDelta">

        <ListView Style="{StaticResource ListViewStyle1}">
            <ListViewItem>A</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>A</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>A</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>A</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>A</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>A</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>A</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>A</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>A</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>A</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>A</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>A</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>A</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>A</ListViewItem>
        </ListView>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

namespace Sample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class TestTextBox : Page
    {
        public TestTextBox()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Grid_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The `onManipulationStarted` will be fired when you drag the list view in X axis.

Comment: Yes in scroll viewer I only require vertical scroll not horizontal. Can you suggest with sample if it possible after that

Comment: Code sample added.

Comment: It is not working as ManipulationStartedRoutedEventArgs doesn't have `Velocities` parameter,the one that I used in Completed event like `e.Velocities.Linear`;

Comment: feel free to add more event handler, like `ManipulationDelta` to get what you need.

Comment: Ok. Can you please check my other question? If you are aware of it?

Comment: I did test and debug, can you put break point ? I update the answer to include full file content.

Comment: checked everything. Please, can you add my code in your application and try. Instead of `navigateToNextPage()` try to navigate it to new page.